# Array find() method not working for case-sensitive words

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, case-sensitive

I am having below array, I am trying to find a word and it is failing as the word in the array and searching word has case differences. How can we solve this?

```
group = ['KIRAN','RAJESH','suresh','aditya'];
name = 'rajesh';
group.find(x => x === name)
```

console output: undefined

```
name = 'RAJESH';
group.find(x => x === name)
```

console output : RAJESH

```
name = 'SURESH';
group.find(x => x === name)
```

console output : undefined

any idea?

Comment: `group.find(x => x.toUpperCase() === name.toUpperCase())`

Comment: @Ivar - although in the whole scheme of things it makes little difference to performance, I would do the upper-case on the name variable outside of the `find` so it doesn't happen on each individual comparison

Comment: thanks Ivar, that is the solution but we have to convert every word into CAPS.

Comment: @user2287528 No, that is the solution that *makes* all words in the array in caps, and works on arbitrary arrays.